# Formula for automorphism between sequence of real numbers

Tags: model-theory

Here's the question:

"Suppose that $r_1<r_2<\ldots<r_n$ and $s_1<s_2<\ldots<s_n$ are two increasing sequence of real numbers. Let $\mathfrak{R} = (\mathbb{R};<)$. Write down a formula for an automorphism $\pi: \mathfrak{R} \cong \mathfrak{R}$ such that $\pi(r_i)=s_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$."

I thought I could define $\pi(m)=m$ for $m \not\in \{r_1,\ldots,r_n,s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$, $\pi(r_i)=s_i$ and $\pi(s_i)=r_i$. (Sorry I do not know how to do the multiline equation with a left brace). After thinking over my solution, I think it isn't an automorphism if I have the sequence $1<2<3<4$ and $2<4<6<8$ as $(r_i)$ and $(s_i)$ respectively, because I believe $\pi$ would not be one-one (4 gets send to 2 and 8).

I've been thinking for sometime now but can't find a way around. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not define it to scale each segment $[r_i,r_{i+1}]$ to $[s_i,s_{i+1}]$, $1\le i<n$?

Comment: I thought of doing that, but I'm not sure how to write down. I seem to remember (from year 1 courses) that we can establish bijection between [0,1] and [0,2], but I forgot how to do that.

Comment: Well, consider the function f(x)=2x. It is an automorphism between [0,1] and [0,2].

Comment: In your suggestion to the solution, 4 gets send to 8 only, it is 2 that gets sent to 4 (not 4 to 2). So you could still establish a bijection.